# drupal7 Webservices create a node

Tags: 7

I am using Drupal 7 and creating a webservice. 
and using **http://delta.indivar.info/tanenttest/drupalgap/node** this webservice. i am trying to create a node using poster plugin of Firefox 
and i am passing parameters as

type='page'

it shows  ["Access denied for user anonymous"]

i can't give permission for Anonymous user. is there is any way so that only authenaticate user can create node.

Answer (score 0):

When using the Poster plugin for Firefox, you need to be logged into your Drupal site in another tab. Then you can use the Node Create resource. Keep in mind that you'll need to pass along the X-CSRF-Token in the header of the request. You can get the token from here, after logging in:

http://www.example.com/?q=services/session/token